# How to create a regex to find a number that contains the exact given numbers in a different order?

Tags: python, regex, numbers

I would like to know how you create a regex in Python where you already have a series of numbers but in a different order.
So I have this number: 3289021
And I need to find the second number of this serie:
3091820
**3289102** 
3018080

The number I am looking for needs to consist of the exact same numbers given. The order doesn't matter.
I tried r'[3289021]{7}, but this time I get all the numbers.

Could someone help me?

Comment: You can find a few ideas by googling 'regex find permutations' or similar, but I would avoid using a regex here. You could split the string and compare each sorted word to your sorted target.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using a regex here. You could split the string and compare each sorted word to your sorted target, like:

```
target = ''.join(sorted('3289021'))
# '0122389'

text = '3091820 3289102 3018080'

out = [word for word in text.split() if ''.join(sorted(word))==target]

print(out)
# ['3289102']
```